# Sorry, `sendotp` does not appear to be a valid operation on this API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to integrate Msg91 for OTP sending. I followed the Msg91 API documentation, and it worked according to that documentation, and I received a 6-digit OTP. However, when I use the same code in my project, it shows an error. Then I tried using the Msg91 package (otp.send("MOBILE_NUMBER_WITH_COUNTRY_CODE")), but this package only generates a 4-digit OTP. Actually, I need a 6-digit OTP. Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

```
import sdk from 'api';
class Msg91Services {
    private template_id: string;
    constructor() {
        this.template_id = process.env.MSG91_TEMPLATE_ID;
    }
    async sendOtp(mobile: string, otp_length: string = '6') {
        try {
            const instance = sdk('@msg91api/v5.0#6n91xmlhu4pcnz');
            instance.auth(process.env.MSG91_AUTH_TOKEN);
            const response = await instance.sendotp({
                template_id: this.template_id,
                mobile: mobile,
                otp_length: otp_length
            });
            console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw { status: error.status, message: error.message };
        }
    }
}

export default Msg91Services;
```

```
const message = await msg91Services.sendOtp('9195XXXXXX28', '6');
```

Error: Sorry, `sendotp` does not appear to be a valid operation on this API.
at Proxy. (/Users/okthursday/Documents/littlemoments-backend/node_modules/api/dist/index.js:179:47)
at step (/Users/okthursday/Documents/littlemoments-backend/node_modules/api/dist/index.js:33:23)
at Object.next (/Users/okthursday/Documents/littlemoments-backend/node_modules/api/dist/index.js:14:53)
at fulfilled (/Users/okthursday/Documents/littlemoments-backend/node_modules/api/dist/index.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
{
status: undefined,
message: 'Sorry, `sendotp` does not appear to be a valid operation on this API.'
}

I need a 6-digit OTP using Msg91. The Msg91 package only generates a 4-digit OTP, and when using the API package, an error occurs. Please help resolve this issue.

Comment: And if you postman or curl `https://control.msg91.com/api/v5/otp?mobile=919999999999&otp_length=6` with your auth? ([documentation](https://docs.msg91.com/reference/sendotp))